# trouble in vscode File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

while i do something changes in setting of vs code then **File seems to be binary and cannot be opened as text** error occurs and not able to do any changes in vs code also not working the setting changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, try win+run and write below:

```
%APPDATA%\Code\User\
```

or macOS:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/
```

or Linux:

```
$HOME/.config/Code/User/
```

inside the folder, you will find the settings.json file or a sync.settings.json - something like that. If you open the files, you may find something like:
NULNULNULNULNUL
Just delete the files and no worries, VSCode will generate new ones in the right format.